# What's best UX practice for a OR/AND search box?

Tags: user-interface, search, checkbox, frontend, user-experience

[image]

I am creating a search box that allows searching for 2 terms, separated by **;** but I want to give the user the option to choose between searching only the profiles that have BOTH terms (if "all" is checked), or to search only the profiles that have one of the 2 terms (if "any" is checked). (in other words, you can consider that semi-column to be either an OR, either an AND, between the 2 terms inserted in the search textbox)

In the screenshot you can see the 2 instances of the checkbox at this moment.
Someone implied that it's not very intuitive, and the learning curve for a new user is pretty high... => My question: Is there any other best UX practice for such a search box?

thank you in advance :)

Comment: [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) is a probably better place to ask your question.

Comment: @Mikey thank you, I will try there also, but there are very few users there :( I think the developer's experience in stackoverflow will be more helpfull

Comment: @cabral_007 Quality over quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, does not looks very intuitive. I think an input with dropdown would be a standard way to do this. Bootstrap has a simple one you can use:
`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#buttons-with-dropdowns`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with the toggle you've used in your mocks is the user doesn't now upfront what options he has. Something like this is more intuitive:

[image]

Also, why do you need the ; in the first place? Can't this just be a whitespace?
This feels very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have to type two terms in? Why are they in the same box?

If it is always exactly two entries, I would do something like this:

[image]

Otherwise, I think this is more human friendly. Having a user think through "and" versus "or" logic might not be a good UX for them (those terms are used a lot in computer science but not in other day-to-day things), so this avoids that:

[image]